# What makes the RegionQ crash for a triangle?

Tags: regions, crash

I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
tri = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 3}];
t1 = Triangle[tri[[1]]]
```

> Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.678106, 0.244129}, {0.70597, 0.351244}}]

Cutting and pasting the above output works with `RegionQ`.

```
RegionQ[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.6781063835026151`, 
    0.24412877439449043`}, {0.7059698790398348`, 
    0.3512444158977386`}}]]
```

> True

```
RegionQ[tri]
```

> True

(* But the following crashes the kernel *)

```
RegionQ[t1]
```

Is there something I am doing incorrectly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have been fixed before  v13.3.1

Comment: Very strange, `RegionQ[Triangle[tri[[1]]]]` works on v12.2

Comment: @UlrichNeumann : I also have v12.2.0 but running on Win7-x64 where it does not work.  I have tried `a` to `z` as variable names. It seems to be `Triangle` averse.